# What is the distribution for random() in stdlib?

Tags: c, random, distribution

The man page claims that the [random](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) function in the C standard library "returns a value between 0 and RAND_MAX."

Unfortunately, it does not say what the distribution is for this random function. Empirically, we can measure it to be uniform, but without documentation, I cannot be certain it will never change when I use it in applications.

Is the distribution documented anywhere?

Comment: uniform. ......................which you could verify easily with a short bit of code....

Comment: @MitchWheat, That's empirical. Is there any standard that guarantees it will always be uniform?

Comment: given that an individual trial does not have a distribution, empirical with sufficient trials is sufficient.

Comment: @MitchWheat, Do you think I can rely on this behavior for other people's machines that I don't have the luxury of benchmarking?

Comment: Yes......................

Comment: The ISO C random number function is called `rand()`. `random()` is the BSD random: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dRandom-Numbers.html#Pseudo_002dRandom-Numbers

Comment: I think if you promise to generate a random number in a range, it is assumed to be a uniform distribution, otherwise you lose some randomness (loss of entropy). In my experience, the only time you mention a distribution for random numbers is if it's something other than uniform.

Comment: The `random` function is not part of the C11 specification. The `rand` function is. So I don't think it's correct to say *"the random function in the C standard library"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither the C standards nor the POSIX specifications define a distribution for `random()` or `rand()`. The manpages for a few systems I checked don't appear to define this either.

I think it's very safe to assume, with the computers that you encounter, that `random()` and `rand()` will produce random numbers which accumulate to (approximately) a uniform distribution, however you can test this empirically if you are unsure.

In general, I think if you promise to generate a **random** number in a range, it is assumed that (as the quantity of numbers goes to infinity) they should accumulate to a uniform distribution, otherwise you lose some randomness (loss of entropy). In my experience, the only time you mention a distribution for a random number generator is if it's something other than uniform (e.g., they might tell you that some specific PRNG will produce random numbers according to a normal distribution).

## Edit (POSIX)

While verifying my assumptions, I ran across a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/drand48.html) family of functions that are defined to generate random numbers in a uniform distribution:

> NAME
>
> drand48, erand48, jrand48, lcong48, lrand48, mrand48, nrand48,
>   seed48, srand48 - generate uniformly distributed pseudo-random numbers
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> double drand48(void);
> double erand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);
> long jrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);
> void lcong48(unsigned short param[7]);
> long lrand48(void);
> long mrand48(void);
> long nrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);
> unsigned short *seed48(unsigned short seed16v[3]);
> void srand48(long seedval);
> ```

FreeBSD's [manpage for `drand48`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=drand48&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) does note that they are not cryptographically secure, and that [`arc4random()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arc4random&sektion=3) is recommended for cryptographic applications. `arc4random()` is from BSD but has been ported to other systems -- it is defined to produce a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4):

The `random(void)` function is not part of the C Standard.  However, (@nwellnhof!) it is part of the POSIX standard.

It is documented in the [glibc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf) and in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/initstate.html).  However, no distribution is guaranteed by either text.

glibc:

> `long int random(void)`
>
> Preliminary:|MT-Safe|AS-Unsafe  lock|AC-Unsafe  lock|SeeSection  1.2.2.1[POSIX Safety Concepts], page 2.
>
> This function returns the next pseudo-random number in the sequence.  The value returned ranges from 0 to 2147483647.
>
> NB:
>   Temporarily this function was defined to return a
>   `int32_t`
>   value to indicate that
>   the  return  value  always  contains  32  bits  even  if
>   long int
>   is  wider.   The  standard
>   demands it differently.  Users must always be aware of the 32-bit limitation, though.

POSIX:

> The random() function uses a non-linear additive feedback random-number generator employing a default state array size of 31 long integers to return successive pseudo-random numbers in the range from 0 to 2^31-1. The period of this random-number generator is approximately 16 x (2^31-1). The size of the state array determines the period of the random-number generator. Increasing the state array size increases the period.
>
> With 256 bytes of state information, the period of the random-number generator is greater than 2^69.
>
> Like rand(), random() produces by default a sequence of numbers that can be duplicated by calling srandom() with 1 as the seed.
>
> The srandom() function initialises the current state array using the value of seed.
>
> The initstate() and setstate() functions handle restarting and changing random-number generators. The initstate() function allows a state array, pointed to by the state argument, to be initialised for future use. The size argument, which specifies the size in bytes of the state array, is used by initstate() to decide what type of random-number generator to use; the larger the state array, the more random the numbers. Values for the amount of state information are 8, 32, 64, 128, and 256 bytes. Other values greater than 8 bytes are rounded down to the nearest one of these values. For values greater than or equal to 8, or less than 32 random() uses a simple linear congruential random number generator. The seed argument specifies a starting point for the random-number sequence and provides for restarting at the same point. The initstate() function returns a pointer to the previous state information array.
>
> If initstate() has not been called, then random() behaves as though initstate() had been called with seed=1 and size=128.
>
> If initstate() is called with 8 <= size <32, then random() uses a simple linear congruential random number generator.
>
> Once a state has been initialised, setstate() allows switching between state arrays. The array defined by the state argument is used for further random-number generation until initstate() is called or setstate() is called again. The setstate() function returns a pointer to the previous state array.

However, if you're using GLIBC, and you want a pseudorandom number function that is guaranteed by standard to produce a uniformly distributed random number over its range then you can use the [SVID random functions](https://uclibc.org/docs/SysV-Interface-vol1a.pdf), `lrand48` and friends:

From page 330:

> The  functions
>   `lrand48()`
>   and
>   `nrand48()`
>   return  non-negative  long  integers  uniformly distributed over the interval [ 0 , 2^31).

These are also [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/drand48.html) as well.

Comment: rand() is NOT random()

Comment: @kfx, The question is not ambiguous. I don't mention the `rand()` function anywhere.

Comment: Actually, `random` is not part of the C standard.  It seems to be part of glibc.  And it is unlikely to have a standard.

Comment: `random` is [standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/initstate.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I've added that.

Comment: @merlin2011, Does this answer your question, or do you still have something lingering?

Comment: This does, but it's a little on the verbose side, so I've accepted the other answer which is slightly more concise.

Comment: One other thing, if you really want a PRNG that's guaranteed by documentation to be uniformly distributed, if that's actually a show stopper for you in some way, then the SVID random functions will do.  See my edit.